# Finding indices of elements that equal zero in the given numpy matrix

Tags: list, numpy, matrix, tuples

I'm trying to find the indices of non-zero elements in a 3*3 integer matrix using numpy as a part of the tictactoe game problem. I realize that np.where is a good option for this case and tried it out, the output I get doesn't look right still. Can you please help me code this part ? I have given my partial code below.

input: s, an integer matrix of dimension 3*3
example:

output: m,a list of possible next moves, where each next move is a (r,c) tuple where r denotes the row number, c denotes the column number.

example:

[code]

```
m = np.where(s==0)
```

Comment: Could you add enough code that it can be run (or should run) and demonstrate the problem? It’s easier to answer if someone can copy / paste it and run it.

Comment: Hi Ryan, the entire code will supposedly be only two or three lines according to my instructor one of which is the where statement. The problem lies with the use of the where statement as that doesn't give the desired output stated.

Comment: It will only be two to three lines of solution, yes, but you're more likely to get answers if you type out a full example that people can run it and answer quickly as opposed to asking other people to do all the typing.

Comment: No what i mean to say is this is the only line of code i had, which returns an output: (array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 1], dtype=int64)) which again is not of the type 'list' which is the reqirement in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution:

```
import numpy as np

s = np.matrix('0, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 0')

m = np.where(s==0)
m = list(zip(m[0], m[1]))

print(m)
```

`s` is the input matrix, where you can see that the middle square is taken, and then we use `np.where()` just like you did, which produces two arrays, then use `zip()` to combine them into tuples and `list()` to convert the output to a list of tuples of valid moves.